# Animation with view flipper to browse web views

Tags: android, viewflipper

I would like do an animation to browse web views, for this, I use viewflipper, when I made the animation with layouts it worked, but with webview, it does not work, I need help from experienced people, here is my code (I copy just the part where there is the problem) :

This is the code with layout, it works well:

```
   vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   int layouts[] = new int[] {R.layout.layout_page1, R.layout.layout_page2, R.layout.layout_page3};

    for (int i=0; i<layouts.length; i++) {
        View vw = vi.inflate(layouts[i], null);     
        vf.addView(vw);
    }
```

and here is the code with WebView does not work:

```
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
    WebView MyWebView[] =new WebView[2];

    MyWebView[0] = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mproof);
    MyWebView[0].setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    MyWebView[0].getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    MyWebView[0].loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    MyWebView[1] = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.example);
    MyWebView[1].setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    MyWebView[1].getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView[1].loadUrl("http://www.hotmail.com");  

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //int layouts[] = new int[] {R.layout.layout_page1, R.layout.layout_page2, R.layout.layout_page3};

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        vf.addView(MyWebView[i]);
    }
```

The debugger stop just after "`vf.addView(MyWebView[i]);`"

Comment: Is there an exception? Post the stack trace please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding two webviews from within the same layout xml a the view flipper would cause some problems.

In the first example you gave you're inflating the views from separate layout files, in the second example you are using findViewById() to get the views, meaning they are in the same layout xml. The problem is most likely the fact that the 2 webviews already have a parent.

Put the webview into its own layout and inflate it.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
MyWebView[0] = (WebView)vi.inflate(R.layout.webview,null);
MyWebView[1] = (WebView)vi.inflate(R.layout.webview,null);

for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    vf.addView(MyWebView[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**
Even taking into account your XML file, the problem is the same thing, that the 2 webviews already have a parent. Which is the ViewFlipper, you are then trying to add them again to the ViewFlipper within the for loop.

Removing this should fix your problem:

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    vf.addView(MyWebView[i]);
}
```

Or use the first solution with an separate xml file for the webview.

Comment: what do you mean by "Put the webview into its own layout" plz ?

Comment: in my xml file, I have this structure : <linearlayout><viewflipper><webview1/><webview2></viewflipper></linearlayout>.

Comment: do you mean I should put each web view in a separate xml file ?

Comment: Ah, I see now. The webviews are already added to the viewflipper in the xml, you dont need to add them with the for loop. I will edit my answer.

Comment: You are right, it worked when I removed the "addview" method . Thanks a lot triggs